# Is it possible to convert blob to pptx?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, blob

I'm struggling to find a solution. I have a blob string of pptx file which I save, as blob, on the server(AWS-sdk). when I download it and try to open it I get an error. What is the right way to save pptx file and then fetch it back?

Edit:

My blob object is fetched from Salesforce ContentVersion Object and the blob is coming from VersionData field, which return blob Object

my js code -

```
uploadObjectToS3(blob) {
        var params = {
            Bucket: this.bucketName,
            Key: 'TEST-UPLOAD.pptx',
            Body: blob,
        };
        this.s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                asd.showToast('Error message', err, 'error', asd);
                asd.spinner = false;
                console.log(err);

            } 
            if (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKsfr.png)

Comment: *"I get an error"* => Please add the content of that error message to your question. And also you're currently just showing us the code of your upload functionality, but the problem is probably rather rooted in the download functionality that's failing.

Comment: You'll want to add some content-type metadata to the S3 object